# Can we load the files from a file location to Named internalstage using stored proc in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Can we load the files from a file location to internalstage using stored proc in snowflake? I understand we cant use the put command here. Kindly help

Comment: An external lambda function could probably be used for this, but not Snowflake stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use Snowflake Stored procedure to PUT files from the local to Internal stage.

Below are few links, which might be helpful:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-use-Variable-Substitution-in-PUT-command-using-Snowflake-Python-connector

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-use-an-ODBC-DSN-connection-in-a-NET-Client-to-put-the-file-to-Snowflake-internal-stage

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a Snowflake stored procedure.  If the file is in cloud storage (AWS,Azure,GCP) then you could setup an external stage and ingest from their directly.  If the file is local, you will need to use a tool to push into Internal Stage.  E.g. Snowsql client, python, .Net, or a tool that can use ODBC or JDBC client.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.
Reason being, that snowflake is running in the cloud, and does not have access to your local computer.

You have to upload your files from local machines into a cloud storage solution, via supported tools, then you are able to use stored procedures to process files.

Below is some additional information

To load a file from a computer or vm to snowflake you are looking for one of two options:

1. Upload to Snowflake Internal Stage via [PUT command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html)
   or
2. Uploading from your computer to Snowflake External Stage via Cloud Provider Tools,

[AWS:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-s3-commands.html)

```
aws s3 cp filename.txt s3://bucket-name
```

[Azure:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-cli)

```
az storage blob upload \
    --account-name <storage-account> \
    --container-name <container> \
    --name helloworld \
    --file helloworld \
    --auth-mode login
```

[GCP:](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)

```
gsutil cp *.txt gs://my-bucket
```

After you have loaded your data into a stage.

If you are unsure what type of stage to use, see [Choosing a Stage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-create-stage.html)

You load the data into your table via [COPY INTO](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html) command

If you are using snowflake internal stage, the following sample script is an upload command that would upload your file.

```
put file:///tmp/data/mydata.csv @my_int_stage;
```

You can run the PUT command from snowsql or python using the snowflake connector for python.

Provide us with the code you are attempting to use and error messages, and we can assist you in moving forward.